# Split phone number in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, phone-number

I need split phone number with format 05XXXXXXXX
and put between "-" for example
05X-XXXXXXX
I need only to put '-' sign between area code and number it self

How I can do that?

Comment: are you sure `-` will be always in 4th place?

Comment: You'll probably want to check this out: [Locale-aware phone number formatting on the iPhone](http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/01/locale-sensitive-phone-number.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you need to put `-` always at 4th place you can do like this

```
NSString *yourPhoneString=@"05XXXXXXXX";
NSMutableString *phoneNumber = [NSMutableString stringWithString:yourPhoneString];
[phoneNumber insertString:@"-" atIndex:3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anoop

```
This is the answer NSString *yourPhoneString=@"05XXXXXXXX";
NSMutableString *phoneNumber = [NSMutableString stringWithString:yourPhoneString];
[phoneNumber insertString:@"-" atIndex:3];
```

Comment: When you accept an answer, you do not need to answer your own question with the accepted answer.